# Kivy Image shows up as a black box on rpi touchscreen

Tags: python, kivy, raspberry-pi4

I have a single-page kivy platform I am working on. The page has two images, one of them appears on kivy just fine (bottle.jpg), the other doesn't(logo.jpg), and is a black box. Both images were showing up just fine a little while ago- I'm honestly stumped by how the imaging system works. Is there a cache I could clear that might make an impact? Maybe something with my code? After doing some digging in other people's past issues I was seeing a full cache as a potential error, but am unaware if this would pertain to the kivy design language.

The photo that isn't showing is 79kb, the one that is, is 35kb.

Kivy Code:

```
(less than) MyFloatLayout (greater than)

    disp_stat:disp_stat
    formula_input:formula_input

    FloatLayout:
        size: root.width, root.height

        Label:
            text: "Welcome To Hell!"
            color: (0,0,0,1)
            font_size: 40
            size_hint: (0.5,0.2)
            pos_hint: {"x":0.2, "top":1}

        Image:
            padding:200
            source: 'logo.jpg'
            size_hint: (0.6,0.25)
            pos_hint: {"x":.6, "top":1}
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: True

        Image:
            padding:200
            source: 'bottle.jpg'
            size_hint: (.4,.4)
            pos_hint: {"x":.1, "top":.7}
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: True

        GridLayout:
            cols:1
            size_hint: (.4,.5)
            pos_hint: {"x":0.55, "top":.8}

            Label:
                text: "Select Your Death:"
                font_size: 24
                color: (0,0,0,1)
```

Python Code:

```
from time import sleep
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder

Builder.load_file('my.kv')


class MyFloatLayout(Widget):

    def formula(self, num):
        print (num)
        self.ids.formula_input.text = ''
        self.ids.formula_input.text = f'{num}'       

    def press(self):
        loaded = self.ids.formula_input.text
        loadnum = int(loaded)

        if loaded == "":
            print(f'Please enter a formula to continue!')
            self.ids.disp_stat.text = f'Please enter a formula'
        
        else:
            print(f'Dispensing Formula {loaded}!')
            self.ids.disp_stat.text = f'Dispensing Formula #{loaded}!'
            self.ids.formula_input.text = ''         
    
class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        Window.clearcolor = (1,1,1,1)
        return MyFloatLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this the answer, as it is presently working- 80kb might have been too big for the image. Upon scaling down the image to the size of my bottle image- things appear to be working fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).